# What design pattern(s) would fit to LOAD-CONVERT-WRITE like scenarios?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I do not want to re-invent the wheel.

Is there a design pattern or patterns that would fit to the workflow below. Idea is to have a **generic solution** that would fit all : LOAD DATA --> CONVERT IT --> WRITE THE CONVERTED

Like:

(1) **LOAD DATA** : Loads data from DataSource and produces an IEnumerable

(2) **COVNERT LOADED DATA** - Walks through the loaded data, and converts them to TConverted type upon a conversion logic

(3) **WRITE CONVERTED DATA** - Walks through the IEnumerable and writes each item into a .txt file

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Pipelines pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28software%29) with a good [C# .NET 4.0 implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx) on MSDN.

The idea is to extract stages, and for each stage schedula a new instance of a TPL's `Task`, then tie all together via `BlockingCollection<T>` instances as intermediate caches.

Also worth noting that mentioned in referenced MSDN paper [BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) returns `IEnumerable<T>` as you want.

General Flow example:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why I need a parallel task? Can you explain? To me it sounds like an operation works in a sequential order...

Comment: You stated that returned data is `IEnumerable` so you can speed out entire process if you will read out by portions and push to Convert so while you reading next data portion previous one already in Convert stage, so this woudl speedup huge data set processing so going to be a generic solution for different data sources

Comment: Makes sense... Would it practically count when I am reading this big data from a SQL Db. with a LINQ query? (Or it would count only if I read with a SqlDataReader?)

Answer (score 1):

The "Template Method" pattern can help you build a generic framework that can be used to implement this process for different kinds of data. There would be an abstract base class like this:

```
public abstract class ETLProcess {
    public final runETL() {
        IEnumerable rawData = extract();
        IEnumerable tranformedData = transform(rawData);
        load(transformedData);
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable extract();
    protected abstract IEnumerable transform(IEnumerable rawData);
    protected abstract load(IEnumerable transformedData);
}
```

And then you can implement the process for different kinds of data by extending `ETLProcess` class. The advantage of this pattern is that you can define your process in the abstract class and individual steps are defined in concrete classes. You can put the common code, common error handling etc in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern. I often think of the conversion as an intermediary class leaning neither to the client nor the adaptee. The idea of a wrapper doesn't always "feel" very abstract. However, it is still probably best to write classes specifically designed to adapt incoming data to what the client expects. If you feel it is violating your abstraction, consider creating base classes or interfaces and implementing those for the specifics of your incoming data.